# CSS Hover to Display Anchor

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to re-create Facebook Messenger's gear icon that is displayed when a chat box conversation is currently active or if the user is hovering over it. 
Not quite sure what to do about hovering...?

```css
    #gear:before {
        color: black;
        content: "\f43c";
        font-family: "Ionicons";
        display: none;
        float: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    #list li:hover + #gear:before{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="list">
       <li class="enter">
           <div class="listContent">
                        
               <a href="#" class="close"></a>
               <span class="name"> Some Name </span>
               <a href="#" id="expand"></a>
               <a href="#" id="gear"></a>

    </div></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your hover rule like this `#list li:hover #gear:before {`

```css
#gear:before {
    color: black;
    content: "ABC";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    display: none;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#list li:hover #gear:before {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="enter">
    <div class="listContent">

      <a href="#" class="close"></a>
      <span class="name"> Some Name </span>
      <a href="#" id="expand"></a>
      <a href="#" id="gear"></a>

    </div></li></ul>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me either, I think it might be conflicting with some previous CSS so I thought `!important` would fix that for me

Comment: @ToniAu As you can see it does work in my snippet, which means if it doesn't work in your code, you have another rule override this one

Comment: Just kidding! I didn't see that you took out the "+", it works, thank you!! Could you explain why you don't need the "+" however?

Comment: @ToniAu The `+` is a sibling selector and your `#gear` is a child of `li`, not a sibling

Comment: Oh I see, that makes much more sense now lol. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy